# Que programa puedo usar en Ubuntu para editar archivos de un Host

Tags: hosting, ftp, terminal

Yo solia usar MobaXterm en Windows para poder editar archivos FTP de un hosting (tienda de prestashop por ejemplo), ahora tengo Ubuntu y no se que programa podria utilizarse para eso.

Pregunta extra: ¿Es posible hacerlo con Notepad++? Si lo hago por ahí dice que acceso denegado...

Comment: Tu pregunta no tiene relación con temas de programación.

Comment: Las preguntas sobre herramientas de programación SÍ son relacionadas con temas de programación.

Comment: @alentin Pregunta: si tú tienes los archivos en el FTP, qué pasa si los descargas y los editas, luego los subes y los reemplazas? No es muy claro el procedimiento en el que te da _Acceso denegado_. Lo otro, podrías editarlos directamente en el FTP usando un editor en consola (como vi, nano o similar), aunque no suele ser una gran idea editar cosas en caliente sobre un ambiente de producción

Comment: Claro, te entiendo, muchas gracias por contestar mi duda @Alfabravo. No se si pueda entrar a el ambiente de producción desde la terminal de ubuntu y acabo de intentar modificar un archivo y subirlo pero no sirvio, estoy buscando una herramienta como el Moba, que tenga los datos FTP y tenga una terminal para editarlos.

Comment: "no sirvió" no nos dice mucho para poder ayudarte. Procura ser más específico, con mensajes de error que encuentres y detalle de lo que intentas hacer. [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/385110/edit) tu pregunta si consideras que hay información que puedes añadir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es un servicio FTP/SFTP en el que estás modificando tus archivos, podrías usar Filezilla client para esa misma tarea de forma similar a como la hacías en entorno Windows.

Te conectas al sitio remoto, buscas el archivo a editar igual que en moba
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya el cliente hará la asociación para abrir el archivo con un editor local.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten presente que lo que realmente estás haciendo a través de la aplicación (como lo hace mobaxterm) es bajar una copia a una carpeta temporal, editarla, guardarla y luego reemplazar el archivo en el servidor con tu nueva versión. CUando cierres tu pestaña de notepad++ o del editor que elijas (kate, gedit son muy buenos y hay varios más), filezilla te avisará que editaste el archivo y preguntará si quieres reemplazarlo en el servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en este proceso tienes problemas, procura ser más específico en los errores que ves (copia y pega el mensaje completo EN TU PREGUNTA).